# How to check for empty string?

Tags: arcpy

I am running a loop to go through tables of a database's feature classes to rewrite the URL links that are currently in the records. The first *elif* statement is to check whether there is an empty string or not and to proceed by doing nothing. I wrote this in because the first *if* statement that also accounts for NULL values does not check for empty strings. Instead, the script just uses the last *elif* and writes the URL with no filename at the end. All other conditions are fine.

```
parish = arcpy.GetParameterAsText(0)
arcpy.AddMessage('Parish Name =  --> "{}"'.format(parish))
field = 'Photo1'
path = r"http://website.gov/Photos/"

for fc in arcpy.ListFeatureClasses():
    arcpy.AddMessage('Processing Feature class -->"{}"'.format(fc))
    rows = arcpy.UpdateCursor(fc)

    for row in rows:
        photolink = row.getValue(field)
        arcpy.AddMessage('Current Photo1 value -->"{}"'.format(row.Photo1))

        if not photolink:
            pass

        elif photolink == "":
            pass

        elif photolink[:4] == "http": 
            arcpy.AddMessage('Photolink If statement worked')
            photolinkMod = photolink.split(r'/')
            photo = str(photolinkMod[len(photolinkMod) - 1])

            arcpy.AddMessage('New Photo1 value -->"{}"'.format(photo))
            row.setValue(field, path + parish + r"/" + photo)
            rows.updateRow(row)

        elif photolink:
            row.setValue(field, path + parish + r"/" + photolink)
            rows.updateRow(row)
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Looks like there are 4 scenarios:

Null values, empty values, http link values, and all other values, which you will turn into file paths.

Whenever you use `elif`, you should really finish with an `else`, to catch all the remaining possibilities.  This is what I would recommend for you: You can combine the first two tests, use rstrip in case a value is a single or multiple spaces, and catch the fourth scenario with the `else` statement.

```
if not photolink or str(photolink).rstrip() == "": 
    pass

elif photolink[:4] == "http": 
    #code

else:
    #code
```